# Synchronizing user inputs over many browsers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

this is a "noob" question i have been wondering about for a while.
In short: I want the user "y" to experience a seamless update of the page when user "x" presses a button that sets a value in the DB in another browser.

something like if(valueHasBeenChanged in DB){add new value to webpage}

Iv been looking on AJAX and JASON tutorials but i cant get the answers i want from the videos.

Is there a easy way to send a XML request every second, or is this bad practice ? Iv been updating the whole page every 30 sec, witch i hate.

Maybe a event listener?

Am i on the right track with : onreadystatechange?

Comment: Take a look at Google firebase https://firebase.google.com/ and meteor.com

Comment: The answer is websockets, but they are a pain to implement, goodluck

Comment: You can use a `setInterval()` which sends a request to a server-side file that monitors the data in the database and returns a response which could spring an action on the page

Comment: Im going to check out the firebase, locks like an easy implementation  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    monitor();
    function monitor() {
        setTimeout(monitor,30000);
        $.post('/your-php-controller')
            .done(function(response) {
                if(response) // do something
            });
    }
});
```

The PHP controller would simply query the database for the information you stored with the client Y's action and return some sort of `json_encode()` response.